# How to create multiple elements in JSON file

Tags: python, json

I want to load the json file into python so that I see multiple elements in the list within a list. My expected result should be (assuming I appended data to an empty list):

data = [[{u'destination-port': u'any', u'source': u'any', u'destination': u'outside', u'protocol': u'tcp', u'action': u'accept'}],[{u'destination-port': u'any', u'source': u'blah', u'destination': u'inside', u'protocol': u'udp', u'action': u'deny'}]]

```
{
    "source": "any",
    "destination": "outside",
    "destination-port": "any",
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "action": "accept"
},
{
    "source": "blah",
    "destination": "inside",
    "destination-port": "8080",
    "protocol": "udp",
    "action": "deny"
}
```

How should my json file be formatted to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

I got the expected result (aside from the mismatch in `destination-port` in `data` vs the test sample) by using this json:

```
[
  [
    {
      "source": "any",
      "destination": "outside",
      "destination-port": "any",
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "action": "accept"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "source": "blah",
      "destination": "inside",
      "destination-port": "8080",
      "protocol": "udp",
      "action": "deny"
    }
  ]
]
```